# Making a Alphabetical letter counter with an array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to program a "letter counter" in C for an assignment using arrays; the only problem is, following our professor's advice, I have no clue and have not been able to find any coding examples or syntax for the program we are building.

Basically, a text file provides text-based input: 
CSC Class - Computer Science Welcome to Online Class

My logic so far is:

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main() {
         char c;
         int letterarray[26];  
         while((c=getchar())!=EOF){  
         } 
}
```

The statement would be, under my current understanding, an if-statement that states if the current character the program is looking at is, say, the letter A, it will increase the value at the index letterarray[0] by +1. If that's possible, and I don't know if it is or how to implement it if so. Does anyone have any advice for implementing this or if this is somehow horrifically erroneous, I'd be thankful just to know that as well.

Thanks for everyone's help in advance!

Comment: Step 1: `char c` should be `int c`, it is a frequent beginner misconception that a character must be a `char`. Step 2: please initialise the letter counts to `0` with `int letterarray[26] = { 0 };` In C local variables must be explicitly initialised.

Comment: This appears to be the start of a *frequency table* (i.e. each slot reports the frequency of a specific character). Worth noting, `c` should be `int`, not `char`; it's important, Related, save yourself the math and make this portable by using `int letterarray[1U << CHAR_BIT] = {0};` . Yes, there may well be 230 entries in that list that you won't need or are interested in, but it will *greatly* simplify the ensuing code.

Comment: Hint: `c - 'a'`.

Comment: @tadman that's _technically_ not portable but since this is a homework assignment OP probably doesn't need to worry about that

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso If they're forcing people to do this with EBCDIC I'd be impressed.

Comment: @tadman just a note for anyone finding this question in the future...

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an empty Integer array with number of element equal to number of letters in alphabet.
2. Think about character as decimal ASCII value:
   'a' = 97 , 'b' = 98, ...

Let `c` be actual letter. Than you can increment field on index `array[c - 'a']` by one, because if u want to increment number of `a` then

`['a' - 'a'] = [97 - 97] = 0`

and so on. This also works for uppercase letters.

Good luck

Comment: It does usually work, but worth noting it isn't portable. The standard only guarantees character sequence continuity for digits. I.e. `0` .. `9` is guaranteed contiguous, and therefore value difference calculations will work. However, `a`..`z` (and `A` .. `Z`) are *not* guaranteed contiguous by the standard.

Answer (score 0):

also as mentioned , look at characters as ASCII values and first initialize `int letterarray[26]={0};` ,then look at this `c -'a'` and `c-'A'` as index of your array elements , so each time you have this index , do `letterarray[index]++;`

look:

```
int main() {
    int c;
    int letterarray[26] = { 0 };
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c >= 'a' && c  <= 'z')
            letterarray[c - 'a']++;
        else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
            letterarray[c - 'A']++;
    }    
return 0;
}
```

Comment: come on, this is clearly stated to be a homework assignment, giving the whole solution is not going to help anyone.

Also, it should be `int c;` instead of `char c;`

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso you're right I should have just explained , but I don't understand why it should be `int c`. can you please explain this?

Comment: The return type of `getchar` is `int`. `EOF` doesn't fit into a character, so if you use a `char` for the result of `getchar`, you can run into errors since `EOF` will get truncated to something else in order to fit it into a `char`.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso thanks for explanation , I updated my code.